# How is the "greater than" or ">" character used in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have seen this character a number of times in CSS files but I have no idea how its used. Can anyone explain it to me and show how they are useful in making a page style easier?

Comment: Be aware that it requires Windows Internet Explorer 7 or later. Or FF or some modern browser. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358819(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358819(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: BTW, > is normally know as "greater than" (or, strictly speaking wrongly, as right angle bracket).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean)

Answer (score 253, accepted):

It's a CSS child selector. `P > SPAN` means apply the style that follows to all SPAN tags that are children of a `P` tag.

Note that "child" means "immediate descendant", not just any descendant. `P SPAN` is a *descendant selector*, applying the style that follows to all `SPAN` tags that are children of a `P` tag or recursively children of any other tag that is a child/descendant of a `P` tag. `P > SPAN` only applies to `SPAN` tags that are children of a `P` tag.

Comment: A note of caution though - it's not supported in ie6

Answer (score 168):

```
p em
```

will match any `<em>` that is within a `<p>`. For instance, it would match the following `<em>`s:

```
<p><strong><em>foo</em></strong></p>
<p>Text <em>foo</em> bar</p>
```

On the other hand,

```
p > em
```

Will match only `<em>`s that are immediate children of `<p>`. So it will match:

```
<p>Text <em>foo</em> bar</p>
```

But not:

```
<p><strong><em>foo</em></strong></p>
```

Comment: Nice, clear example. although tpdi's answer was helpful, this one really made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 9):

this is known as a Child Combinator:

> A child combinator selector was added
>   to be able to style the content of
>   elements contained within other
>   specified elements. For example,
>   suppose one wants to set white as the
>   color of hyperlinks inside of div tags
>   for a certain class because they have
>   a dark background. This can be
>   accomplished by using a period to
>   combine div with the class resources
>   and a greater-than sign as a
>   combinator to combine the pair with a,
>   as shown below:

```
div.resources > a{color: white;}
```

(from http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/18/css3-selectors.html)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> E > F
> ```
>
> Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

more on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 0):

The **child combinator** (**>**) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the **direct children** of elements matched by the first.

[Child combinator more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)