# :hover with ">" in CSS

Tags: html, css

It's a silly question, but well. What version is the ">" in CSS? I can't find it in google because I don't know the name of this.

Example.

CSS

```
.test {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;}

.test .color {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    background:red;}


.test:hover > .color {
    background:blue;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="color"></div>
</div>
```

What version of CSS it is? 2 or 3? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the "greater than" or ">" character used in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746525/how-is-the-greater-than-or-character-used-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called the child selector, and it is part of CSS2.

Documentation at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

> A *child* selector matches when an element is the child of some element. A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".

Answer (score 2):

It marks the immediate child of a node. Hence its name "child selector".

So in your case `.test:hover > .color` selects any node with the class `color` that is an direct child of a hovered node with class `test`.

For more information have a look at the [respective MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors).

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is for direct descendants.

So `div > div` will select all `div` elements that have a direct parent element that is also a `div`.

It is CSS 2.

It was recommended for CSS 3 selectors as well.

See on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

That would be a CSS selector for that is directly below (in the document tree) another element.  As in it's child element.

This CSS3 cheat sheet is very helpful: [CSS3 Cheat Sheet](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/css3-cheat-sheet/css3-cheat-sheet.pdf), not only for answering the question you have but other uncommon selector types.

You can also find what is supported on what browswers with this: [Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3...](http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+7,ie+8,ie+9,ie+10,firefox+3.6,firefox+19,chrome+25)