# What's the meaning of ">" in the osmosis selector?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, osmosis

I'm reading a tutorial about using [node-osmosis](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis) at [this page](https://hackprogramming.com/web-scraping-in-node-js-with-multiple-examples/).

Does anyone know the meaning of `>` in `.paginate('#navcnt table tr > td a[href]', 5)`?

I cannot find the explanation of this symbol in the [document](https://rchipka.github.io/node-osmosis/index.html) page.

What's the default selector of node-osmosis? Its [github](https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis) page says it supports Sizzle selectors, Slick selectors, and more.

How to know which selector I'm using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a css selector, it means direct child.

More information: [How is the "greater than" or ">" character used in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746525/how-is-the-greater-than-or-character-used-in-css)